# Custom IServiceProvider in WPF

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to add a custom `IServiceProvider` in WPF for use in markup extensions?
I'm not finding any relevant documentation or examples.

Comment: I don't think it's possible; why do you need it? There's probably another way to do what you want...

Comment: I want to add a language translator service for use in my localize markup extension. I've done this before using a static service object, but there's this nice interface in ProvideValue just begging to be used. It would also play well with IoC's then.

Comment: OK, I can see how that would be useful... unfortunately, the IServiceProvider is provided by the XAML processor, and I don't think you can add your own services to it. If you do find a solution, please post it here, I'd be glad to know it.

Comment: You could get an IRootObjectProvider reference from the standard service provider and the RootObject from this is basically yours (the containing Window for example), so it could implement an IServiceProvider itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, dependency injection and WPF don't combine well. They should have used a factory model to create the WPF components instead of just using `new`.

Comment: [The docs are pretty clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/service-contexts-with-type-converters-and-markup-extensions) about this being internal behaviour that they don't want to expose. Instead of using statics for everything I put a static readonly `IServiceProvider` in a wrapper and I register/expose my custom services through that instead. Still not ideal, but at least a bit cleaner than the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The ProvideValue method lets you override anyways whatever logic you desire to overcome the shortcoming of overriding IServiceProvider. I have not tried out the code below, instead it is a sketch of how we could design a custom service provider, preferably as a singleton and other functionality that is usual to add in a dependency inversion framework. You should use the IServiceProvider that is naturally available in your solution due to framework / libs being used or add a DI framework yourself to register interfaces and concrete types.

The MarkupExtension will need to override ProvideValue. You can ignore the IServiceProvider argument here and instead use something you have control over yourself (that is, another IServiceProvider)

```
  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider
    serviceProvider)
    {
     //retrieve objects from a custom IServiceProvider instead
     var someService = someCustomServiceProvider.GetSomeInstance<ISomeService();
     //use someService to do desired functionality and finally return the object to return in the ProvideValue method here.

}
```

Where we have some service provider we implement ourselves :

```
public class SomeCustomServiceProvider : IServiceProvider {

    private readonly Dictionary<T, Func<T>> _registry;

    public SomeCustomServiceProvider(){
     _registry = new Dictionary<T, Func<T>>();
    }

    public void RegisterService<T>(Func<T> createFunc){
     _registry[T] = createFunc;
    }

     public override object GetService(Type serviceType) {
      return _registry[T]();
     }

}
```

Instead of writing a small DI framework yourself, either use the DI framework which you already are using, e.g. Autofac or similar, or make use of a simple container registry. There are a lot of such small frameworks, I have just added a sample here as an illustration. One example of a DI framework can be SimpleInjector:
[SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/)