# Can I pass my own service via MarkupExtension.ProvideValue's IServiceProvider argument?

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter, valueconverter, markup-extensions

Is it possible - in a WPF, .NET Framework app, to inject my own, user-defined services into the `IServiceProvider` argument received by `MarkupExtension.ProvideValue`?

Typically I've made all my value converters derive from Markup Extension merely so I could create them inline in attribute bindings if I desired (instead of declaring them as StaticResource).

Like this:

```
public class MyConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    //  (IValueConverter implementation here... blah blah blah...)
```

I've never used that `IServiceProvider` argument but there it is, already available to me.  [The documentation talks about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/service-contexts-with-type-converters-and-markup-extensions) built-in services I can use there.  But is there any way to register my ***own*** services sometime when my application starts so that my markup extension could then retrieve them?

(I already realize I can use MultiBindings, I'm just trying to understand if I can avoid them in some cases)

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29848410/1136211

Comment: No, I did not.  (I thought I searched pretty diligently but I guess not) Anyway that's clearly that's an answer to my question.  Thank you.

Comment: I should say I tried using the IRootObjectProvider approach that one of the commenters on that thread mentions but that doesn't work very well.  Quite often, that approach finds me only the control in which the markup-provider is used but is unable to navigate to the root main window.  Not sure why